# Is it good coding practice to assign a value to the function at the beginning of the function?

Tags: vbscript, standards

I am being questioned about my coding style and I do not agree with my reviewer.

I write my function like this..

```
Function Func_DoSomething(argVariable1, argVariable2)
    strStringSame = ""
    Func_DoSomething = Array(False,strStringSame)

    If argVariable1 = "" Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    If argVariable2 = "" Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    If StrComp(argVariable1,argVariable2,vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
        print "Yes!"
        strStringSame = "Same"
    End If

    Func_DoSomething = Array(False,strStringSame)
End Function
```

My reviewer suggests that I should not be assigning an array or even a variable to the function at the beginning of the function instead do something like this.

```
Function Func_DoSomething(argVariable1, argVariable2)
    strStringSame = ""

    If argVariable1 = "" Then
        Func_DoSomething = Array(False,strStringSame)
        Exit Function
    End If

    If argVariable2 = "" Then
        Func_DoSomething = Array(False,strStringSame)
        Exit Function
    End If

    If StrComp(argVariable1,argVariable2,vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
        print "Yes!"
        strStringSame = "Same"
    End If

    Func_DoSomething = Array(False,strStringSame)
End Function
```

I know both the ways are functionally possible because both the methods work. However I am being told that what i am doing is incorrect and the viewer of my code will get confused.

Is there any truth in that, is my coding style not a good style?

Comment: Straight from MSDN: `"To return a value from a function, assign the value to the function name. Any number of such assignments can appear anywhere within the procedure."` I think the first line is just as reasonable as anywhere else. Maybe even moreso. After all, VBScript returns its own "default" values (empty string, False, etc.). I would think the place to override this default would be the first line of the function.

Comment: Also I tend to assign false to the function variable and a true at the end. The motive is if ever there is an in the function i'll just exit and it will exit with False. if there is no error, it exists with true which also works. I am being told variables are not assigned the value of False when initializing and it is a wrong coding practice...i don't agree to it but how to i convince otherwise.

Comment: I do the same, except I don't even bother to initialize it as `False` at the beginning. It's `False` by default. Technically, it's an _uninitialized variant_ by default. But an uninitialized variant can be treated as an empty string (`""`), the numeric value `0`, or boolean `False`. Works the same in VB/VBA. Even typed variables have default values in VB/VBA (`""` for `String`, `0` for `Integer/Long`, `False` for `Boolean`, etc.). Seems a shame not to take advantage of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible answers:

1. As you just "write [your] function like this", i.e. have no reason whatsoever for your 'coding style', do as you are told.
2. Your reviewer's arguments - "that's wrong" and "I'm getting confused" - are irrefutable. As (s)he pays/grades you, do as you are told.
3. Both functions smell: The first element of the returned array is useless/always False; the second element is either "" (invisible) or "Same" (error prone and inefficient), so should be Boolean; there are multiple exit points; there are side effects (print). As one more possible smell doesn't matter, do as you are told.

The real world problem - a function returning true iff both string args are non-empty and case-sensitive equal - can be solved by writing the specs in VBScript syntax:

```
Option Explicit

Function f(s, t)
  f = s <> "" And t <> "" And s = t
End Function

Dim aa : aa = Array( _
     Array("", "a") _
   , Array("a", "") _
   , Array("", "") _
   , Array("a", "b") _
   , Array("a", "a") _
   , Array("a", "A") _
)
Dim a
For Each a In aa
    WScript.Echo "|" & Join(a, "|") & "|", CStr(f(a(0), a(1)))
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 25453765.vbs
||a| False
|a|| False
||| False
|a|b| False
|a|a| True   <-- non-empty and case-sensitive equal
|a|A| False
```

Look ma: no coding style problem at all.

So the base rule is: Exactly one `function-name = return-value` statement after the computings, i.e. at the end.

Possible deviations:

Exploit VBScript's feature **not** to combine "specify return value" and "exit the function" into one statement (like `return(whatever)`) to do late clean-up:

From a class that uses a .NET System.Text.StringBuilder to do fancy formatting:

```
Public Function formatOne(sFmt, vElm)
    m_oSB.AppendFormat sFmt, vElm  <--- much more computings could be here
    formatOne = m_oSB.ToString()   <--- specify return value *before* the end
    m_oSB.Length = 0               <--- late clean-up
End Function ' formatOne
```

Specify return value at the top, because it is *not* determined by the computations; e.g. init functions for a class that must return `Me`:

```
Class C
Private m_x
Function init(x, lots, of, parms)
  Set init = Me
  m_x = x
  use lots of parms
  ...
End Function
```

**I** would put the assignment of Me at the top, so I can't forget it; but I would accept the argument "everybody looks at the end of a function to determine the return value" - and do as I'm told.

Setting the default return value early for efficiency:

```
Function isin(a, s)
  isin = False
  For Each e In a
      If e = s Then
         isin = True
         Exit Function  <--- algorithm needs break here
      End If
  Next
End Function
```

I wouldn't like using a temporary variable here.

To sum up: Try to write functions like f(); have reasons when you want to deviate from the default rule; don't argue with the hand that feeds you.

Comment: 1. A piece of code reflects my unique identity. It is my understanding that a developer (if I may call myself that) is given a problem which can be solved multiple ways but (s)he selects one way which they think is most efficient and codes accordingly. I assumed that a reviewers role was to review the logic, identify code errors, logic errors not tell me that I should be coding their way.
2. That hand doesn't grade or feed me. :)
3. You are correct, the first element is kind of useless. In the real function I am generating the two return values which will always be unique.

Comment: That said, I have decided to write like my reviewer just to avoid the hassle. I will not be returning a boolean value unless it provides some value. Unfortunately I am unsure whose answer to select as I believe both the answers present valid points.